# Sending a pointer from a function

Tags: c, variables, pointers, parameter-passing

This is just something I was wondering.
Well here goes,
Say I declare a variable in a function, I pass this variable as a pointer to another function.
What happens with this variable when the first function (where the variable is declared) ends?
Does it stay on the stack or does it get removed when the function ends?

Thanks in advance =D

Comment: It depends on the storage specifier for the variable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When the function you define a variable returns the variable is destroyed, *unless* you declared it static. Check storage classes in C. Here is a pointer: http://aelinik.free.fr/c/ch14.htm

Answer (score 1):

When the first function ends the variable is destroyed, hence the pointer becomes invalid.

Answer (score 1):

If you declared this variable on stack it will disapear:

```
void foo()
{
    int varInStack;
    foo2(&varInStack);

    // when foo returns, you loosed your variable.
}
```

You may return it:

```
int foo()
{
    int varInStack;
    foo2(&varInStack);

    return varInStack;
}
```

Comment: Returning it doesn't keep the pointer from dangling, though.  Any pointers to the local variable are invalid once the function returns.

Comment: Different answers. So returning it from a local scope destroys the pointer anyways?

Comment: @Davey: Nope.  The *pointer* still exists; it just points to FSM-knows-where once the *variable* is destroyed.

Comment: @cHao of course, this is the first example I wrote, you loose the variable. In the second example I show how to get the variable value

Comment: @Davey Here is no pointer. I declared an int variable, not pointer. Now, I use it to get a value from `foo2()`. When I return it from `foo()`, there is a copy of it in stack that you can get. The original variable declared inside `foo()`is lost, but you have a returning copy

Comment: What if you wouldn't return the value of that, but the pointer to that variable, what happens?

Comment: @Tio: Just wanted to clarify that you're not returning the variable; you're only returning its *value*.  The variable still gets destroyed, and any pointers to it would still become invalid.

Comment: Thanks guys for the discussion =)